# How to convert a VHDL code in Verilog using Icarus Verilog?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, icarus

I can't find an example in doc to convert a VHDL code to Verilog with icarus. I found how to do verilog to VHDL [here](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Using_VHDL_Code_Generator).
I tried to modify the command to do VHDL convertion on [this code](https://github.com/Martoni/blp/blob/master/vhdl/src/button_deb.vhd) :

```
$ iverilog -tvlog95 -o button_deb.v button_deb.vhdl 
button_deb.vhdl:3: syntax error
I give up.
```

But I've got a syntax error. Is my VHDL code is wrong ? Or is it iverilog command that is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some support has arrived in the meantime (mainly using `-g2005-sv`, `-g2009`, or `-g2012` switch) . Try this:

```
iverilog -g2012 -tvlog95 -o button_deb.v button_deb.vhd
```

If you pay closer attention to the output you'll see that in this way you'll loose the two `generic` at the entity interface. Using `vhdlpp` directly could be useful:

```
/path/to/vhdlpp button_deb.vhd > button_deb.v
```

Comment: Thanks claudio, I found another way to do the convertion this year : the ghdl-yosys plugin.

Comment: @FabienM: Could you give a small example on how you did this conversion with the ghdl-yosys plugin?

Answer (score 2):

There's no Verilog target, so you can't generate Verilog output, and VHDL compilation is still experimental anyway. You could ask on the mailing list to make sure there's nothing under the hood which could help. VHDL to Verilog conversion is only possible in relatively simple cases (synthesisable code should be Ok), so you may have to do it manually anyway.